# ag-grid-angular not working in IE11, but fine with Chrome

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using **ag-grid-angular(^20.1.0)** in my project. that grid is not working in IE11.
[image]

But Working on **Chorme**
[image]

**I tried to change height and weight, but still not working in IE11.**

it's working fine with Edge.

Comment: Any errors in IE console?

Comment: No error on IE.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to 20.2 fixed this for me.